# Get aggregation of data from each numpy sub-array

Tags: python, numpy

I have such an array:

```
arr = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]).reshape(2,2,4)

array([[[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
        [ 5,  6,  7,  8]],

       [[ 9, 10, 11, 12],
        [13, 14, 15, 16]]])
```

And I want to get to get the max for each of these sub-arrays:

```
arr[:,:,-1]

array([[ 4,  8],
       [12, 16]])
```

So I would want each of these sub-arrays converted to their max value. As result:

```
array([8, 16)]
```

How would I be able to do that without iterating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use max in numpy:

```
arr[:,:,-1].max(-1)
```

-1 is your last dimension.

printing it:

```
  [8, 16]
```

Comment: The question is, how to get the max aggregation out of these arrays. I.e. to end up with [8, 16]

Comment: It is a bit confusing. are you looking for `arr[:,:,-1].max(-1)`? It will give you `[8,16]`. but if you mean something else by aggregation, could you please explain more how you get the output? Thank you

Comment: Another possible thing that results in the same output is `arr.max(-1).max(-1)` if you were looking for this.

Comment: Sorry just realized myself that my question originally wasn't clear. Specified it. But your comment gave me the answer I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: I will edit the post. Please feel free to accept it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC you want the output to be `[8,16]` which is a max of the sub-arrays `arr[:,:,-1]` that you have computed. Try this -

```
arr = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]).reshape(2,2,4)

np.max(arr[:,:,-1],-1)
```

```
array([ 8, 16])
```

Comment: hmm. Isn’t this an alias of posted answer?

Comment: As i see it, your answer was edited after mine to reflect the righr answer. Previous answer posted by you was not the complete solution.

Comment: The question was not clear to me originally. However, I also posted it in my comments beforehand. Nonetheless, it could be good to have the function version of it for learners too.